# Why is the text widget underlined?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Hey guys I have a question. I tried to ad a new text widget in my code (just as always), but it is red underlined. I don´t know why. In my opinion everything is right. I copied the same text widget one line below and in that line it isn´t underlined. Can anybody say my what the reason therefore is? (I added a link in which you should find the part of the code.

This is the code

[pic of the widgets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tUxq.png)

Comment: I found my problem

Comment: Answer your question in the answer box, is good practice to copy directly the code in the question instead of upload a picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `,` after RaisedButton.

```
Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Button"),
            onPressed: (){

            },
          ), // <--- here
          Text("Simple"),
          Text("simple"),
        ],
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

It's underline because it's missing a comma before your Text Widget :

```
RaisedButton(
  child: Text(startStopButtonDesign),
  onPressed: () {
    startOrStop();
  },
), //Missing commma
Text(_time.toString()),
```